# rollback change in database without use @transactional for spring test

Tags: hibernate, jpa, rollback

I'm creating a test that need save data in the database, so I can't use `@Transactional` because I need that the data effectively save in database, the question is without use `@transaction` is possible rollback the transaction after the commit?

Comment: Spring will automatically rollback tests that are marked `@Transactional`. Within the scope of the test method, you should still be able to query the database for previously persisted data.

Comment: @crizzis yes, but the idea is not use `@Transactional` because I need the commit in the test

Comment: You can have have a clean up method annotated with @After, to clean up your database after each test.

Comment: Could you please describe your use case (why you think you need to commit the transaction)? Like I said, all the beans joining the transaction will see the data modifications. Unless your test involves multiple threads or spawning a child transaction, you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Your database should be in a known state before each test and no one test should depend on the outcome of another. If you need to commit for some other reason, troubleshooting the test for example,  then you can annotate your test class or individual test methods with:

`@Rollback(false)` or `@Commit`

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#rollback

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#commit

> @Rollback indicates whether the transaction for a transactional test
>   method should be rolled back after the test method has completed. If
>   true, the transaction is rolled back; otherwise, the transaction is
>   committed (see also @Commit). Rollback semantics for integration tests
>   in the Spring TestContext Framework default to true even if @Rollback
>   is not explicitly declared.